I have a question about kernel of the following map.
Let $k$ be algebraically closed field, $f \in k[x_1,...,x_n]$. Let
$$\begin{align} \pi : k[x_1,...,x_{n+1}] &\longrightarrow k[x_1,...,x_n]_f\\
g(x_1,...,x_{n+1}) &\longmapsto g(x_1,...,x_n, \frac{1}{f(x_1,...,x_n)}) \end{align}$$
I think Ker($\pi$) = $(x_{n+1}f-1)$. Clearly Ker$(\pi) \supseteq (x_{n+1}f-1)$. I don't know Ker$(\pi) \subseteq (x_{n+1}f-1)$. How do I prove this.

Is $\pi$ even well-defined? It is not whenever $f$ is not a constant non-zero polynomial considering the current definition. Perhaps, you should reconsider which is the codomain of $\pi$.

I'm sorry I forgot to write about it. k[x1,...,xn+1] is polynomial ring that is defined on U.  U is the set of zeros of xn+1f-1. Then f is constant non-zero polynomial isn't this? So is this map wel-defined?
